# Dimmer will only work with one specific LED--what might be going on?

Tags: led, dimmer-switch, lamp

I have a dimmable, single-bulb, lamp from Crate & Barrel. The socket says it can take bulbs up to 150w. It came with a dimmable 1w LED bulb which works fine, but is not very bright. I have tried to replace the bulb with a 60w incandescent bulb, but it does not light up. The same has happened with dimmable 6w and 6.5w LED bulbs from Ascher and Philips--none of them light up. In all cases the dimmer itself has a small light that lights up indicating that current is going through the bulb. All the bulbs work in other sockets around the house.

What might be going on?

Comment: Is the dimmer part of the lamp or in the wall? What model # is the lamp?

Comment: The dimmer is integral to the lamp in the sense that it is a plastic box attached to the cord (it's all from Crate & Barrel). The dimmer says it is model no. SC-233 (120v AC, 50/60Hz, 600W 5A, Tungsten

Comment: That sounds like "Take it back to Crate & Barrel and ask them why it isn't working" to me.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging the lamp, then using a wooden tongue depressor or similar instrument to pry up the center contact in the lamp socket slightly?

Comment: I agree with the others (and no time to write up a formal answer): (a) if fairly new, take it back for exchange or refund, and if you want an exchange, bring a bulb with you so you can confirm it works; (b) if not so new, unplug and try to pry up center contact as that *may* be the issue.

Comment: Bending up the center contact did not make a difference, and also seems to rest on a hypothesis that can't explain why the original 1w LED bulb works fine (but is not bright enough for my taste)

Comment: Any chance this is more than a dimmer and is actually a low voltage power supply or driver?  Is it a standard E26 Edison socket?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - how would I know that?

Comment: @histelheim looking at the lamp literature or the writing on the dimmer module or bulb.